# How can I use 2 threads at the same time for bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm having some issues to make work a code i took from a tutorial :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data

I tried connecting this way :

```
_spinnerBT_Devices.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        _Selected_Device = (BluetoothDevice) _BT_Devices_list.get(i);
        _printf.setText(_Selected_Device.getName());
        _myThread = new ConnectThread(_Selected_Device);
        _myThread.run();
        _myService = new MyBluetoothService.ConnectedThread(_myThread.mmSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //_myThread.cancel();
    }
});
```

And write on my serial bluetooth :

```
public void buttonUpClick() {
    _buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _printf.setText("Debug : UP");
            if(_myService.mmSocket.isConnected()){
                _myService.write("z".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But as soon as I try to write on it, the app crashes, like it can't use two threads at the same time.

edit : I can write but only one time and it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

It wasn't about having 2 threads but the code was crashing cause of that part :

```
// Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                    Message writtenMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                    writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
```